# ListView ItemActivate Delay

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, listview

I have a ListView with the Activation property with HotTracking. There appears to be about a 2 second delay between when the user clicks the item and the event fires. Is there a way to get the event to fire immediately upon the user click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found no way to change this delay, it's a built-in setting.

Problem is, the MouseDown event actually has a delayed reaction, only setting the SelectedItems property **after** it has fired.

You have to do this manually: use the MouseClick event. This will fire if an item is clicked, even if its an already selected item. It will *not* fire when empty space is clicked.

```
Private Sub list_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles list.MouseClick
    Dim item As ListViewItem = list.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)
    If Not IsNothing(item) Then
        do your stuff here
    End If
End Sub
```

You can simulate hot tracking by handling this event

```
Private Sub list_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles list.MouseMove
    Dim item As ListViewItem = list.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y)
    If Not IsNothing(item) Then
        list.SelectedItems.Clear()
        item.Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the SelectedIndexChanged event instead!

Comment: Thought of that, but it won't work if the item is already selected.